# Dynamically adding custom meta tags

Tags: reactjs, next.js, metadata

I've been trying to figure out how I could dynamically add the "og:video:secure_url" meta tag to my page. but all the examples and doc references I see show you how to add tags from a selection that nextjs lets you add by default. I can add video.other like this for example

```
openGraph: {
  type: "video.other",
  url: videoURL,
},
```

but it doesn't let me add one the same way for video.secure_url? is there no way for me to just give it the html for the meta tags I want to add? I've noticed that it was possible with the Head component but that's no longer an option in nextjs 14. Would appreciate any help! Ideally I would like to be able to just write the html instead of going through this API

I've tried looking through the generateMetaData docs but can't seem to find what I'm looking for

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you can follow this link. may be this will help you to solve your problem.
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata